# running PHP verbosely in an interactive session

Tags: php

I am using PHP interactively by typing `php -a` at the command line. I have modified /etc/php5/cli/php.ini to load an extension module which I built using SWIG.

When I terminate the interactive session, I get a segmentation fault:

```
root@yourbox:~$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > ^DSegmentation fault
root@yourbox:~$
```

I would like to run php in verbose mode so that I can see the calls that lead up to the seg fault. Is there a way to run php verbosely in interactive mode?. For example, with Python, one can run `python -v` to get detailed diagnostics. Is there an equivalent with PHP?

**[[Update]]**

Here is a stack trace when using valgrind:

```
root@yourbox:~$ USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0 valgrind php -a
==16414== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==16414== Copyright (C) 2002-2011, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==16414== Using Valgrind-3.7.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==16414== Command: php -a
==16414== 

valgrind:  Fatal error at startup: a function redirection
valgrind:  which is mandatory for this platform-tool combination
valgrind:  cannot be set up.  Details of the redirection are:
valgrind:  
valgrind:  A must-be-redirected function
valgrind:  whose name matches the pattern:      strlen
valgrind:  in an object with soname matching:   ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:  was not found whilst processing
valgrind:  symbols from the object with soname: ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Possible fixes: (1, short term): install glibc's debuginfo
valgrind:  package on this machine.  (2, longer term): ask the packagers
valgrind:  for your Linux distribution to please in future ship a non-
valgrind:  stripped ld.so (or whatever the dynamic linker .so is called)
valgrind:  that exports the above-named function using the standard
valgrind:  calling conventions for this platform.  The package you need
valgrind:  to install for fix (1) is called
valgrind:  
valgrind:    On Debian, Ubuntu:                 libc6-dbg
valgrind:    On SuSE, openSuSE, Fedora, RHEL:   glibc-debuginfo
valgrind:  
valgrind:  Cannot continue -- exiting now.  Sorry.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a stack trace using the usual tools for C debugging. For example:

- Valgrind:

  ```
  $ USE_ZEND_ALLOC=0 valgrind php -a
  ```
- GDB:

  ```
  $ gdb php
  > r -a
  ```

If you don't get meaningful stack traces you might need to recompile PHP with debug symbols and with reduced optimization. You can do so by passing `--enable-debug` to your `./configure` line.

Comment: +1 for info that is useful. I am using gdb for now though I would like to use valgrind. I have accepted your answer, but updated my question with the error I get when I run valgrind as suggested. Please take a look and reply when you have the time. Thanks.

Comment: @HomunculusReticulli You should try out what the error message suggests, i.e. `sudo apt-get install libc6-dbg` (if on Ubuntu). Seems like you are missing some kind of debugging symbols (though I don't really know what exactly it needs).

Answer (score 0):

You are probably going to want to use `valgrind` or alike to track down exactly where your PHP install is Seg Faulting.

Most likely, the error will be related to the extension you have loaded, which may not be compiled to the right architecture, contains a leak, or something else.